# calculate number of Android's linear acceleration sensor values in one second

Tags: java, android, sensors

Can anyone help to solve this problem. 
how to calculate number of Android's linear acceleration sensor values in one second?

Answer (score 0):

Register your `SensorListener` over the linear acceleration sensor. For each value retrieved, aside of incrementing the total amount of values, you can use something like `SimpleDateFormat` to check time and if you add the time between each value you can stop your loop when it exceeds 1 second.

`System.currentTimeMillis()` will be even easier if you're just testing.

Comment: Thank you very much PeterGriffin